# Gerrit revision workflow: merge conflicts and re-approval

Tags: gerrit

We are considering using Gerrit for the large project. At this point it would be interesting to know how people are dealing with merge conflicts of approved changes.

Imagine, that many changes of different size are pending revision simultaneously, and they are being reviewed and verified gradually. Since some of them might be modifying the same piece of code, the conflicts are inevitable. It is not a problem if "integrator" accepts patches manually in a simple workflow, small conflicts can be resolved on the way, but with Gerrit things are different. When the change has been reviewed and approved, in case of merge conflict, as I understand, it will need to be rebased by the author and pushed for revision again, in which case revision process starts again. In the relatively active projects, with more than 50 external contributor commits per week, this might turn into nightmare, if revision of the same patch might be required to be done several times due to merge rejection after each approval and submit, which seems to be not efficient.

Questions:

1. Am I correct that Gerrit is not a way forward for the large and active stuff where the large number of merge conflicts is expected?
2. Some merge conflicts can be trivial, is there a way to resolve them without the need of bothering author to recommit the change?
3. If the change needs to be backported to stable branch(es), I guess the separate change for each branch needs to be pushed for revision, even if the cherry-pick is clean.

General comments about your Gerrit workflow experience are also welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Gerrit is used by some really massive projects, such as Android and the related bsp, kernel, etc repositories.  These projects get way more than 50 external commits per week.  I think Qualcomm will have several thousand commits in about that amount of time.
2. There is a setting in Gerrit to auto-merge trivial conflicts.  This can be set per-repository.  If this option is set, the change is merged in based on your submit strategy (cherry-pick, merge if necessary) after the change has been reviewed and verified and a user presses the 'Submit' button.  The best documentation I could find for this is here http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.3/cmd-create-project.html#_options under the --use-content-merge option.
3. Yes that is typically how we do things.  There are other options (bypassing review, merging branches, etc), but cherry-picking to the needed branches and reviewing works well.

Answer (score 4):

We want to keep our history clean and understandable, and therefore reasonably linear. So we have configured Gerrit to use only fast-forward merging. The only visible merges are for release and support branches (we're using git-flow) which makes things much easier to understand.

However, we have the trivial-rebase plugin installed so that previous review status is automatically applied to the rebased change. This happens regardless of whether rebasing is done in Gerrit (using the Rebase button) or by the developer rebasing locally and re-pushing the change.

In our experience, merge conflicts are actually less common in a large project, due to the much larger number of source files involved. We have around 16,000 files in the repo and 30 full- or part-time developers, so the probablility of editing the same file is quite low.

In any case, if two developers are making changes to the same part of the same file, they really should be talking to each other. If the project architecture requires frequent changes to the same file (eg a registration table of some kind) the architecture needs to be redesigned, to use something like dependency injection, or to generate that source file automatically from fragments as part of the build.

Comment: Neil, I'd love to hear more about your gerrit + git-flow workflow.  Have you documented it anywhere?  Thanks.

Comment: @spazm https://github.com/sillsdev/FwDocumentation/wiki is all we have right now, and it's aimed at our internal developers. However, if there's anything else you'd like to know, feel free to contact me directly. We're still refining our processes so interaction with others who are following the same path is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

When we hit a merge issue at our company, the developer rebases and pushes to gerrit.  If the merge was minimal, he's allowed (by convention) to LGTM the rebase and submit.

We are still debating if/when developers should rebase when updating patchsets.  The UI gets confused when comparing between patchsets when the parent changes.

Comment: We try to ensure that rebases don't include any other changes, so it's easier to separate real updates from rebasing noise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it for a few weeks after using mercurial for a couple of years with a feature branch merged into default mode and I'm hating gerrit. I find myself with more overhead solving trivial conflicts that are solved automatically by merges on mercurial or git in non-gerrit mode. Then everybody uses the argument android uses gerrit ergo gerrit is good and should work for everybody.